# Jquery mobile value overrides toFixed method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check:

http://jsfiddle.net/LdWHH/

Obviously it does not make sense to set it to toFixed(1) first and then to toFixed(2). The point is that the .slider("refresh") seems to have its own internal conversion and thus it ignores or overrides the toFixed method. I don't know.

In my german browser it also displays the . correctly as ,

How can I adjust this manually?

```
$("#plus3").on("mousedown taphold", function () {
  var sv4 = $('#slider-vertical4').val();
  var sv4fixed = Number(sv4).toFixed(1);
  var total = (Number(sv4fixed) + 0.1).toFixed(2);
  $('#slider-vertical4').val(total).slider("refresh");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve.

If your problem is that using `+/-` : 5.0 will appear as 5.

You can try doing it in two times, `set&refresh` then `set`

```
$('#slider-vertical4').val(total.toFixed(1)).slider("refresh")
$('#slider-vertical4').val(total.toFixed(1));
```

Comment: Yes that is my problem exactly. If I remove .slider("refresh") the slider won't move anymore which, of course, is not the desired solution.

Comment: It seems like a fine workaround. I am sure there is an elegant solution too, but this is good enough for now. Thanks!